# IE11 hangs when loading google.com

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

This is an odd one. I am running IE11 on Windows 10 64 bit. My default web page is http://www.google.com. When I open the browser, Google hangs and will not load. Eventually it will time out and I receive the following error:
[image]

HOWEVER, if I then click my HOME button after this, Google loads just fine! I have checked my TLS settings in Settings>Internet Options>advanced and all versions of TLS are enabled as well as SSL 3.0. I have tried clearing the browser cache and history, but NOT cookies and website data as I can't delete all of my user's saved passwords. Interestingly, this occurs in BOTH the 32 bit and 64 bit IE versions on this PC, but does NOT occur in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Please reset your advanced IE settings. The error message clearly refers to the *server* configuration, not yours. You may have degraded security by changing advanced settings.

Comment: I did click the button to reset advanced settings a couple of times already, and it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: It is possible some of the settings in the Internet Zone on the Security tab of Internet Options might have been changed -- could any of these settings be the culprit?

Comment: @user1780242 Considering you reset your IE settings that is indeed possible.  Restore them to what they previously were.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My advice was purely to restore sane security settings (e.g. disabling SSL 3.0 and whatnot), not solve the problem. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

These problems can have several reasons and workarounds :

- Try to disable your antivirus to see if it is the cause of the problem.
  BitDefender Antivirus Plus 2018 was specifically
  [mentioned](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/not-able-to-connect-to-secured-sites-like-google/dce0a98f-dd11-4ef8-a7da-da680df319e7?auth=1).
- This problem can arrive if your computer has incorrect date or time.
- The website uses a security protocol that is not enabled:
  Open Internet Options, Advanced Tab, scroll down and under Security
  ensure that these options are all selected : Use SSL 3.0, Use TLS 1.0, Use TLS 1.1 and Use TLS 1.2. Click Apply and OK.
- InPrivate Browsing is said to be a workaround for the problem.
- If you are using Microsoft Insider software, expect bugs.

Comment: I’m using Malwarebytes and already tried disabling that with no effect. All of these security protocols are already enabled — that was the first thing I looked at. We’re not using Microsoft Insider. I’ll check the system time — i have seen that cause issues. Will post back after checking this.

Comment: I checked the system time and date and it was correct. I reset the security settings to default and still no joy.

Comment: Try to run Internet Explorer in Safe Mode (without add-ons) by using the `-extoff` parameter : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff`.